# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ssl

After forcing SSL manually using the following code in wp-config.php file :

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
// in some setups HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO might contain 
// a comma-separated list e.g. http,https
// so check for https existence
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

the website worked just fine, and for couple days i no longer can access my website and the " ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED " error

Any thoughts guys or suggestions please ?

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: @kero No that's why i forced it, cause i used to have trouble using https, the website load with no Css and Js, and when i forced it via the shared code it worked just fine. but not it's doesn't work when i use https instead of http

Comment: The "ERR_CONNECTION_.." is coming from your browser. You need to have a valid certificate, otherwise https will not work. Are you behind a proxy that serves the requests with https?

Comment: if i may ask sir, how can i check this ?

Comment: Proxy: you'd have to ask your hosts probably, but I'd guess you don't have one if you don't know about it.

Comment: Is your web server definitely set up to server traffic on port 443? i.e. if it's Apache do you have mod_ssl loaded and `Listen 443 https` somewhere in your config? Does `curl https://localhost/` connect, even if it gives you a certificate warning? (Note that you really need to try the non-localhost address of the server, but localhost might work - does for me on EC2)

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply sir, the problems seemed to be in .htaccess file, now everything is working fine again...Thank you so much sir for your time and fast replies